# Django Comment, append symbol to the url comment?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-comments

im using the comment system, now, i would like to re-write the segment form the url comment and append a symbol #, i want to move the page seccion to the comment list exactly to the last comment user with `<a name=#{{comment.id}}?> username </a>`

Im using next for redirect the usen when the comment was posted:

```
{% get_comment_form for object as form %}
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="POST">
  {{ form }}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}" />
  <input type="submit" name="preview" class="submit-post" value="Preview"></td>  
</form>
```

But in the Django Doc dont say nothing about rewrite or customizer the comment redirect / url

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just stumbled across this little bit of ugliness.  After reading the source code I didn't see any nice way to override this behavior.  By default you are redirected to the URL in the template's `{{ next }}` variable and Django appends a `?c=1` to the URL where the `1` is the ID of the comment.  I wanted this to instead be `#c1` so the user is jumped down the page to the comment they just posted.  I did this with a little bit of "monkey patching" as follows:

```
from django.contrib.comments.views import utils
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def next_redirect(data, default, default_view, **get_kwargs):
    next = data.get("next", default)
    if next is None:
        next = urlresolvers.reverse(default_view)
    if get_kwargs:
        next += '#c%d' % (get_kwargs['c'],)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)

# Monkey patch
utils.next_redirect = next_redirect
```